# How to force child element adherence to `flex: nowrap;` CSS directives

Tags: javascript, css, svg, flexbox

I have a couple of d3.js animations on-screen at the same time, each governed by CSS  `display: flex;` and `flex: nowrap;` directives, the only telling difference between the problematic one (which wraps) and other, correctly-displayed (ie non-wrapping) animations being that:

- because it has non-svg header and text input elements, it comprises anchoring `div` or `section` elements. (As I understand, these, being block-level, theoretically occupy the entire available display width, and so have, in the css file, been 'overridden' with the setting `display: inline;`.
- overflowing svg path elements, whose length has now been physically curtailed so as to match the limits of the containing svg:svg element.

Frustratingly, the animation steadfastly refuses to be governed by the `flex: nowrap;` directive.

**The question:**

Is there a general approach to ensuring that flex row nowrap behaviour is determined by what is actually visible on-screen, and not by containing (or sibling) block-level elements such as `section` or `div`, or wider but `overflow: hidden;` child svg `line`s or `path` content?

Note: other questions/answers on this topic relate to text, not section, div or svg.

All animations are theoretically governed by the parent `flex-flow: row nowrap;` setting.

The associated widths are such as to allow plenty of free space around each.

It would be nice to think the parent `flex-flow: row nowrap;`, taken together with the svg:svg element's `overflow: hidden;` and the block-level `display: inline;` CSS settings would be enough to ensure that no wrapping occurs. I have checked in the inspector, and all dimensions displayed lie within limits required for `flex-flow: row nowrap;`.

The only elements in play are `section` (or `div`), `text`, `svg`, `g`, `input`, `ul` and `li`. In practice, something is leading to unwanted wrapping. My feeling is that the block-level elements are the source of the problem. Can you suggest a strategy to avoid this?

Failing this, are there alternatives I can use as containers for text input elements which are less likely to cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, the answer arrived during sleep.. :-)

Firstly, use of display: inline; on block-level elements seems not, at least in this situation, have the effect on width claimed by some bloggers (in fact tends to pollute the parent flex context).

This in turn led to a search for alternative **inline** elements to replace `div` or `section`. On substituting the inline element `span` in place of the block-level elements `div` or `section`, the desired `nowrap` behaviour immediately took effect, but in turn knocked out my (now local) vertical block layout. This was restored using `display:inline-block;` on the containing span, so:

**originally (somewhat simplified):**

```
     ---------- header
    /
div--- svg:g -- svg:svg (with overflow:hidden;)
    \
     ---------- user text input area
```

..which, despite a parent `nowrap` directive, was caused to wrap by the div (or other block-level) element.

**now:**

```
     ---------- header
    /
span-- svg:g -- svg:svg (with path extents matching those of svg:svg container)
    \
     ---------- user text input area
```

..whereby span has the css `display:inline-block;` directive set on it **and** a width specified. Here, the parent flex nowrap directive was adhered to, but locally (ie inside the span) the block layout is applied.

Comment: Seems I'm not the only one to have encountered this [problem](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/kSY5t/)